# Python Selenium socket error - [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, sockets, selenium, port

I'm using Selenium 2.25.0 with Python 2.7.1 bindings on a Mac. I'm encountering a socket error when I run this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import selenium 
import unittest, time, re, base64, urllib, httplib, urllib2

#Create Selenium object
browser = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.com/")
#Start browser
browser.start()
```

And then on the last step (`browser.start`) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.25.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/selenium.py", line 189, in start
    result = self.get_string("getNewBrowserSession", start_args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.25.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/selenium.py", line 223, in get_string
    result = self.do_command(verb, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.25.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/selenium.py", line 212, in do_command
    conn.request("POST", "/selenium-server/driver/", body, headers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 941, in request
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 975, in _send_request
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 937, in endheaders
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 797, in _send_output
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 759, in send
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 740, in connect
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I've tried fiddling with different ports, but this does not solve the issue. Apologies if there's something obvious I'm missing here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before running the script you must start the server. Go to the directory where Selenium RC’s server is located and run the following from a command-line console. You can find more instructions [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#installation).

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version-number>.jar
```

Comment: Thanks! Whoops, that's obvious.